# AWS Cloudwatch Log logs a Lambda function only once

Tags: logging, aws-lambda

I'm new to aws and use a Lambda function triggered by an event.

The weird thing is that I get a log entry only the first time after I update the lambda function code or configuration.

Subsequent executions are not logged.

I expect that logging lambda executions are always done.

Why is it happening this way?

Answer (score 0):

The logs are sent to CloudWatch on every execution but note that there are different log streams, and each execution's logs could be written to a different log stream.

Also, some logs could be written only when the Lambda code is loaded in the first time, if you have a code that runs on import (this could be dependent on your runtime language).

Comment: Hi Ronyis, I'm aware of both what you mentioned. I get different streams but only when I trigger the lambda after I have deployed the function again

Comment: Logs should be written whenever a data is written to stdout (calling 'print()' in python for example). If you think that this is not the behavior you have encountered, you should give more details about your specific case.